# Django app and Wordpress page on same VServer but different domains

Tags: django, wordpress, apache, nginx

I have one virtual server with 2 domains configured. One domain should host a wordpress page and the other domain will be a django web application.

I did some research, but I am confused. I know that for Wordpress Apache is the way to go. But for Django I often read that Nginx is the best setup.

My question is: What is the best practice in terms of web server setup when hosting 2 domains on the same (virtual) server, where one domain hosts a wordpress page and the other domain hosts a django web application?

Answer (score 0):

My answer is based upon my own server. You can use Wordpress with Nginx without any problems. Personnaly, I have 2 Wordpress website and a Django web application on the same server with Nginx.

I used these documentations to set up all of this :

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-debian-8#create-a-gunicorn-systemd-service-file

I hope that this will be useful for you,

Best regards